# Cannot Execute Commands in Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

My code is

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount(r"/content/drive")
!ls
```

The mount is successful, but the last command gives the following error:
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories:

```
Transport endpoint is not connected
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Transport endpoint is not connected
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: My Drive: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Did I mount it wrong? What's the fix here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
drive.mount(r"/content/drive")
```

Use:

```
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```